# DateTime('first day of April') returns same as DateTime('first day of May')

Tags: php, datetime

April ant May returns same date in php:

`var_dump(new DateTime('first day of April'));` - `'2016-05-01 00:00:00'`

`var_dump(new DateTime('first day of May'));` - `'2016-05-01 00:00:00'`

Works great for other months, `but for April it returns 05 instead of 04`.

Edit: 'timezone' => 'Europe/Paris'

Edit2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xPIq.jpg

Comment: You check this as  Indian Standard time?

Comment: that's strange: https://3v4l.org/GteBt - on PHP 5.5.24 - 5.5.33, 5.6.8 - 7.0.5 it is working but the other versions get the wrong date.

Comment: can you do the same and show me: http://imgur.com/dI5IvMH

Comment: @DanieleD eddited my first post with img

Comment: adding the year solves the problem: https://3v4l.org/PDXM3

Comment: @sebastianbrosch you are correct, adding a year shows 04. `new DateTime('first day of april 2016')` works aswell (without the timezone). Dont see where to mark as answered in a comment..

Comment: You need to check [this user contributed example of Mark Simon on docs](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php#118062)

Comment: Same problem without the year for date(): https://3v4l.org/EJt8M

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very strange behavior, but I found some solutions to get the expected results. The reason why this is not working is the missing year on the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/de/class.datetime.php) object.

**solution #1 (https://3v4l.org/hIA89)**

```
<?php
    $datetime = new DateTime('2016-01-01', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris'));
    var_dump($datetime->modify('first day of april'));
    var_dump($datetime->modify('first day of may'));
?>
```

**solution #2 (https://3v4l.org/PDXM3)**

```
<?php
    var_dump(new DateTime('first day of april 2016', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris')));
    var_dump(new DateTime('first day of may 2016', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris')));
?>
```

**solution #3 (https://3v4l.org/pBH0n)**

```
<?php
    var_dump(new DateTime('1 april', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris')));
    var_dump(new DateTime('1st april', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris')));
    var_dump(new DateTime('1 may', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris')));
    var_dump(new DateTime('1st may', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Paris')));
?>
```

> thx to @Glavic

Comment: Or just use `1st April` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using this in Indian standard time than use this:

```
public function indiantime() {
    $set_date_time = date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
    $get_time_zone = date_default_timezone_get();
    $actualdatetime = new \DateTime();
    return $actualdatetime;
}
```

Comment: var_dump(new DateTime('first day of April', new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata'))); still returns 05

Comment: Have you set the  date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata")

Comment: yup, still returns the same.